# How to profile and understand output for a Java Web App

Tags: java, netbeans, profiling

I am currently trying to profile a java web app. I used Netbeans Profiler in conjunction with Eclipse. My server (Tomcat) is running through eclipse plugin and I dynamically connect to server using Netbeans profiler.

I have a primary problem, that after sometime server runs out of memory on an environment. I read about the memory leak and I realized that there are two ways:
1. Large objects sit in memory stay un collected and cause memory leak OR
2. small objects keep getting assigned in memory without being collected.

Although second one is usually hard to find, one usual symptom is that over a period of time, the gerenerations surviving garbage collection would keep increasing, irrespective of speed. And it seems to happen in my web app, although no activity is really taking place. The generations increase over a period of time, steadily and without exception. Forcing me to think that I have some refrenced objects somewhere which should have been garbage collected.

I ran the tests with profiler but unfortunately I don't really understand as to how to pin point the object. I noticed that one specific HASHMAP had surving generation count consistently increasing even though I garbage collected several times.

I am attaching a simple screen shot giving a very brief overview of what I saw in next few min of starting application.

I would be grateful if you could point me out to some real articles etc which would enlighten me as to how to make sense of profiling and what is it that I should go about doing to ensure I catch the culprit.

Any help is much appreciated.

Find the screenshot attached.
[alt text http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1264228/Files/State.png](http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/1264228/Files/State.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to detect a memory leak in any application (Java or not) is to take periodic snapshots of memory, while the application is in use, followed by a close examination of the object count for the different types of objects managed by the application.

Most memory leaks can be traced to a group of objects that show the largest increase in memory consumption. Briefly stated, one should give priority to Δ MEM(objects) as opposed to Σ MEM(objects).

Once you have identified the set of objects responsible for the leak, you then need to pinpoint the source of the leak, via the object allocation trace.

For a quick introduction, on how to do this with Netbeans, you can take a look at one of the tutorials at [Java Passion](http://www.javapassion.com/handsonlabs/nbprofilermemory/).

In Eclipse, you will find the MAT plugin's ability to depict the dominator tree to be very useful.

Finally, the following list of terms would be useful, since efficient analysis requires knowledge of these as pre-requisites:

- [Generations](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/gc/gc_tuning_6.html#generations)
- [Garbage Collection root](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/MemoryAnalyzer#Garbage_Collection_Roots)
- [Dominator tree](http://kohlerm.blogspot.com/2009/02/memory-leaks-are-easy-to-find.html)

Answer (score 1):

I generally take a couple of heapdumps each few seconds apart just to see the pattern of what is being released and what might be sticking around.

Then I drill down into the objects that are suspicious and find what is holding the reference to them. Often it boils down to some resources not being closed properly, excessive use of session objects, static variables, leaks in some class loaders, inmemory cache or some object in a list that is still being referenced to.

It not always easy to go through though hundreds and thousands of objects and interpret what's going on. I have found this [course](http://www.javapassion.com/javaperformance/) on JavaPassion to be very helpful to a beginner.